# SQL Server Never Ending when Join Two Tables

Tags: sql-server

I have one source table in DB. I need to do group and sum to get one bridging table, extract supplier info on the other bridging table then join the two using part_number.

If I run the subqueries separately, T1 gives me 54699 records and T2 gives approx 10 times rows of T1.

Next, I do left join, I expect it should return 54699 records, but the server engine never stops and it returns 50 million records at the time I scroll down to the end. I have to stop the query manually. I realized there must something wrong with my query, but I can not figure it out. I would appreciate it if you have any ideas. Thank you!

```
SELECT 
    T1.*, T2.SUPPLIER 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         T.PART_NUMBER,T.YEAR, T.WEEK, 
         SUM(T.QTY_FILLED) TOTAL_FILLED,
         SUM(T.QTY_ORDERED) TOTAL_ORDERED, 
         COUNT(T.LINE_NUMBER) ORDER_TIMES
     FROM 
         DBO.TABLE1 T
     WHERE 
         T.YEAR IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         PART_NUMBER, T.YEAR, T.WEEK) T1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         T.PART_NUMBER, T.SUPPLIER
     FROM 
         DBO.TABLE1 T) T2 ON T1.PART_NUMBER = T2.PART_NUMBER 
ORDER BY 
    T1.PART_NUMBER, T1.YEAR, T1.WEEK
```

I also tried the window function, but still no luck.

```
WITH T1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        T.PART_NUMBER,T.YEAR, T.WEEK, 
        SUM(T.QTY_FILLED) TOTAL_FILLED,
        SUM(T.QTY_ORDERED) TOTAL_ORDERED, 
        COUNT(T.LINE_NUMBER) ORDER_TIMES
    FROM 
        DBO.TABLE1 T
    WHERE 
        T.YEAR IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY 
        PART_NUMBER, T.YEAR, T.WEEK
), T2 AS
(
    SELECT T.PART_NUMBER, T.SUPPLIER
    FROM DBO.TABLE1 T
)
SELECT 
    T1.*, T2.SUPPLIER 
FROM 
    T1 
LEFT JOIN 
    T2 ON T1.PART_NUMBER = T2.PART_NUMBER 
ORDER BY 
    T1.PART_NUMBER, T1.YEAR, T1.WEEK
```

Comment: Try adding DISTINCT to your T2 subquery -  `T2 AS (SELECT DISTINCT T.PART_NUMBER, T.SUPPLIER FROM DBO.TABLE1 T)`

Comment: A more generalized approach start with a small subset of your data containing a handful of part numbers that also have a variety of suppliers, orders and dates.  Build and debug your query using that, and only after working out the problems with that should you move up to the big data. Part of your problem is that the data you hav to work with is seriously denormalized. The same table contains parts, orders, and suppliers and I suspect that the relationship between orders and supplier may not be well defined. If there is any way to redesign your source, start there.

Comment: @TN Thank you! I believe 99% there are no relationships at all. I do not think they have set up a primary key or a foreign key, they just using DB as a PURE place to store data(Each table is totally separate from the other). Data is stored in a very inconsistent and unstructured way.

Comment: _I believe 99%_ Why do you "believe" and not "know"? Who exactly are "they"? But "T2 gives approx 10 times rows of T1" only indicates that you have 5million rows in the table as it does not filter or aggregate. Most likely you need to apply DISTINCT to the T2 query at a minimum. But if a given PART_NUMBER has multiple suppliers, then what is your goal? If you join T1 to T2 on PART_NUMBER alone, you will get a row for every supplier of each part number (per year and week).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it not only return 54699 rows. You do a join without distinct, so the result could be the join of 50.000 x 5.000.000 rows and it depends on the value of your table.
If you use SQL 2017 or newer, try something like this:

```
SELECT 
         T.PART_NUMBER,T.YEAR, T.WEEK, 
         SUM(T.QTY_FILLED) TOTAL_FILLED,
         SUM(T.QTY_ORDERED) TOTAL_ORDERED, 
         COUNT(T.LINE_NUMBER) ORDER_TIMES,
         STRING_AGG (SUPPLIER, ', ') AS SUPPLIER
         
     FROM 
         DBO.TABLE1 T
     WHERE 
         T.YEAR IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY 
         PART_NUMBER, T.YEAR, T.WEEK
```